# Assigning a name to a number

Tags: java, random, naming

I'm currently writing a program involving random card selection and I'm wondering if there is a way to   get the program to replace the numbers 11, 12, and 13 with jack, queen and king respectively? I could use an if statement to detect values greater than 10 but that would force me to write the same code around 4 times which seems counterproductive. Any and all responses greatly appreciated!

```
int card0 = (cardGenerator.nextInt(13) + 2);
        int winTest = 4;
        while(winTest > 0)
        {
            Object[] highLowEqual = { "higher", "lower", "equal", "Quit" };
            Object userChoice = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
            "The current card is " + card0 + ". Which do you think the next card will be? Remember: Ace is the highest possible.", "HiLo",
            JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, null,
            highLowEqual, highLowEqual[0]);
            int card1 = (cardGenerator.nextInt(13) + 2);
```

Comment: Write a method. That's how you avoid writing the same code 4 times.

Comment: Use an `if` statement, or maybe a `switch` statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a `Card` class that knows how to print itself:

```
public class Card
{
    int rank; 

    // ...

    public String toString()
    {
        switch( rank )
        {
            case 1: return "Ace";
            case 2:
            case 3:
            case 4:
            case 5:
            case 6:
            case 7:
            case 8:
            case 9:
            case 10: return "" + rank;
            case 11: return "Jack";
            case 12: return "Queen";
            case 13: return "King";
            default: return "INVALID CARD RANK";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some piece of code has to do the replacement and that code has to go somewhere. As commented by khelwood and answered by clcto, you can possibly override the toString() method and put the logic for replacement in there.